# Symfony 4. Unregister ObjectNormalizer

Tags: php, symfony

I want my serialization process to be explicit, without using Object/Property normalizers, how do I unregister them?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#normalizers

Comment: Your english is not understandable, sorry ... Please rewrite your question

Comment: @Mcsky updated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way by adding compiler pass in `Kernel::build`:

```
class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    // ...

    protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new class implements CompilerPassInterface
        {
            public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
            {
                $container->removeDefinition('serializer.normalizer.json_serializable');
                $container->removeDefinition('serializer.normalizer.object');
            }
        }, PassConfig::TYPE_BEFORE_OPTIMIZATION, 1);
    }
}
```

Priority = 1 makes it run before `SerializerPass` so it works.

**UPD**: @Nek's advice to disable serializer in `framework` config and register it myself seems like a good idea.

Comment: If you want to remove automatic configuration of the serializer, you can just disable the serializer from the framework bundle: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#serializer . This means that the "serializer" service does not exists anymore and you need to register it by yourself with (potentially) your own normalizers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your serialization process to be explicit, you can register your own normalizer like follow in a services `definition`

```
AppBundle\Serializer\Your\MyObjectNormalizer:
    tags:
        - { name: serializer.normalizer }
```

You could declare a normalizer like follow

```
namespace AppBundle\Serializer\Your; 
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

class MyObjectNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface
    {
    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        // $object is an instance of MyObject
        $groups = array_key_exists('groups', $context) ? $context['groups'] : [];

        $data = [
            'name' => $object->getName()
            // ..........
        ];
        if(array_key_exists('full', $groups)) {
            $data['owner'] = $object->getOwner()->getFullName();
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the given class is supported for normalization by this normalizer.
     *
     * @param mixed  $data   Data to normalize
     * @param string $format The format being (de-)serialized from or into
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return $data instanceof MyObject;
    }
}
```

If you process like follow Symfony will see that you declared a custom normalizer for this kind of object. So he'll take your class in first priority to normalize `MyObject`

You can normalize data from the context array

```
$myobject = new MyObject();

$fullObj = $this->container->get('serializer')->serialize($myobject, 'json', ['full']);

$lightObj = $this->container->get('serializer')->serialize($myobject, 'json');
// $fullObj is ['name' => 'someName', 'owner' => 'ownerName'];
// $lightObj is ['name' => 'someName'];
```

Take a look at this part of the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#adding-normalizers-and-encoders)

Comment: I know that  I can register my own normalizers that will have priority over standard, but if I forgot to add a normalizer or messed up `supportsNormalization` then it will be normalized by ObjectNormalizer since it is registered.